# Using FC 19 - How can I interact with very long menus?

Tags: fedora, gnome, gedit

I am using FC 19 with the default Gnome setup. Assuming this is Gnome shell, some version 3.

Some common apps have very long menus. An easy example is Gedit and the languages menu. This is so large that it is taller than my desktop. I have looked in gconf-editor, and have searched the internet - I cannot find a way to get either a scrollbar, or columns or some other way to see all the options in the menu.

How can I see and select options in this long menu?

Comment: And yes - I am aware I can get to the specific gedit options with view->highlight mode. It still stands that the toolbar language selector is too long for the screen. I can also see this on pycharm when context clicking folders in a project view. I am sure I can find other examples.

Comment: That's a defect and you should report it as such. https://bugzilla.gnome.org/ There's no reason you should have to configure something to not do something so stupid no one would want it that way.

Comment: Yes - that is fair enough. I wandered if there was just some Gnome trick I was missing - the trend seems to be that all window controls are disappearing making things harder to use currently.